# Should this noun be plural or singular

Tags: grammatical-number

I was reading an article and came across to the following sentence.

Rock fulgurites, found almost exclusively on the peaks of mountains, appear as a thin crust on the surface of rocks.

What I couldn’t understand was why the words 'surface' and 'crust' are singular. As it says the peak***s*** of mountains, I thought these two words should be plural. Can someone explain why they are singular?

Comment: This is the **distributive singular** used to convey a _universal_ concept.  Consider "Hold your protractor down with your left hand and mark the angle in pencil, holding the pencil in your right hand, girls" (left-handers having been primed to reverse instructions). Neither 'crusts' nor 'surfaces' is _wrong_ here, but 'crusts' could imply a layered effect (more than one crust per surface), and the three-word prepositional phrase 'on the surface' is so idiomatic that it pulls strongly towards 'on the surface of' here. // The near-juxtaposition of plural and singular takes getting used to.

Comment: So it would be correct either way, but the author chose to use universal with distributive singular. Is this true?